# Javascript Special Characters coming back incorrectly

Tags: javascript, firefox, special-characters, read-eval-print-loop

There is a page where I have certain special characters on and when retrieving values of these via javascript I am getting an odd conversion. The character 'Œ' is coming back as 'R' and its lower case version 'œ' is coming back as 'S'. Is this a limitation of javascript or could it possibly be the browser. This is from testing in firefox. Also this is being retrieved via a repl client (Jssh/MozRepl) so it seems that it could be an issue with these clients themselves rather than the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have an encoding problem somewhere.  There are many opportunities to mis-handle the encoding of text.  If you post some code, we might be able to help you find it.

Comment: var outstream = transport.openOutputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_BLOCKING , 0, 0);
this is the output stream I am using in javascript (not much I can configure in firefox from what I can tell as the docs dont help too much)

Comment: apparently firefox has the nsITransport streams set to UTF-8 so any characters above 255 are not showing up correctly.

Comment: Can you share how you managed to fix it? maybe some sample code will help.

Answer (score 0):

Output streams aren't scriptably safe for non-ASCII characters so you will need to wrap the stream in a nsIBinaryOutputStream, a nsIUnicharOutputStream or a nsIConverterOutputStream.

Comment: I just ended up converting them to an array of character codes and outputting that and converting it instead. It was only with characters above the 255 char codes. I haven't seen good documentation of nsITransport but can you open any of those streams using openOutputStream?

Comment: What you do is you pass your existing stream as a parameter when you initialise the wrapper stream.